# Ms Excel having error while cross nesting level

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have more 27 arguments to add in the below but it will cross nesting level of 64 so anyone has an Idea to escape nesting level.

> =IF(D10="710saturday",6.14,IF(D10="710Friday",6.14,IF(D10="710Sunday",5.12,IF(D10="710Monday",5.12,IF(D10="710Tuesday",5.12,IF(D10="710Wednesday",5.12,IF(D10="710Thursday",5.12

Comment: You should re-write your algorithm to reduce nesting. Use better checks like `IF(ISNUMBER(CONTAINS("710", D10)), ISNUMBER(CONTAINS("saturday", D10)), ...` instead of checking for equality on every possible value combination, or use multiple cells to achieve your purpose, then hide those cell columns.

Answer (score 0):

Create a static table as shown below and then perform `VLOOKUP`with your data.

[image]